# Google Now time estimation to work

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, google-now, aokp

I have an Galaxy SII, and I'm using AOKP JB Milestone 1. That said, I'm experiencing something strange, the Google Now app is running and working just fine, except for one thing, I've set my home and work address, but it just shows me the estimated arrival time for going home, all the time by the way(except when I'm home), and it never showed the estimated arrival time for work.

Is it known, or may be just and ROM bug?

Answer (score 1):

How long have you used the feature? On my GNex, it took roughly 2 work weeks for the feature to adapt to my work hours, which are 8:00-16:00, so not that complicated. If you're working in shifts or by some other schedule, it might take longer for the feature to learn when to show which destination.

Comment: I think it's about 2 weeks.. I thought it would learn more quickily, but I'll wait then